# SQL Server Merge Replication using Web Synchronization - RESUMING SYNC

Tags: sql-server, replication, master-slave-replication, merge-replication

We are using MSSQL Merge Replication using Web Sync over extremely slow connection with many SQL Express subscribers.

For some reason, occasionally, connection is dropped and the subscriber is trying to re-connect and start downloading again the whole packages.

Is there any way for the subscriber to resume downloading, using existing downloaded packages, before connection drop?